# React routing is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Register from './register/register';
import Login from './login/login';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  NavLink
} from 'react-router-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
const history = createBrowserHistory()


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.register = this.register.bind(this);
  }
  login() {
    history.push('/')
  }
  register() {
    history.push('/login')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>

          <button onClick={this.login}>Login</button>
          <button onClick={this.register}>register</button>


          <Route exact path='/' component={Register} />
          <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        </div>
      </Router>

    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have two pages of Login and register,i wanted to route these pages calling method as above.But url is changing but page is not loading.i searched for some solutions and i followed,but it's not working,please check what's wrong with the code.Thank you

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors in console

Comment: Your `login` method pushes state to `/`, and not to `/login`. Is it correct? Doubt if it has anything to do with your initial problem, but anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to bind `history` to router:

```
<Router history={history}>
  ...
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`withRouter HOC`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) to provide the history as a prop to the component and then you can make use of `this.props.history`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.register = this.register.bind(this);
  }
  login() {
    this.props.history.push('/')
  }
  register() {
    this.props.history.push('/login')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>

          <button onClick={this.login}>Login</button>
          <button onClick={this.register}>register</button>


          <Route exact path='/' component={Register} />
          <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        </div>
      </Router>

    );
  }
}

const App = withRouter(App);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

First one is you missed your binding operations

```
<Router history={history}>
  ...
</Router>
```

then make sure into your webpack config files having this code

```
devServer: {
historyApiFallback: true,
contentBase: './' }
```

in module.exports module.

Happy Coding !!!!